# Using an ideal as an index set

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Algorithmic Algebra by Mishra, the sum and intersections of submodules of $M$ (an $S$-module) are defined using an ideal $I \subseteq S$ as an index set for a family of submodules, $\mathcal M = (M_i)_{i \in I}$.

i.e

$\sum_{i \in I} M_i = \{\sum_{i \in I} x_i \mid \text{all but finite $x_i \in M_i$s are 0}\}$

and

$\bigcap_{i \in I} M_i $ (defined the usual way).

To me using an ideal as an index set is quite a weird/counter intuitive idea. Is there a place where this could be useful/desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum and intersections are defined for modules indexed by an arbitrary *set* $I$. An ideal $I$ is *more* than just a set with extra properties; it comes with extra *structure* and therefore is not just a set. Every ideal $J$ has an *underlying set* $|J|$ and of course with respect to that set we can define families of modules etc., but this has nothing to do at all with the ideal structure because it has been forgotten.

Simple example: $\sum_{x \in |J|} R \cdot x = J$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what you are saying is that using an ideal $I$ or rather $|I|$ as the index set, doesn't have an extra benefit over using an arbitrary index set? (What I wanted to know was, whether there was a benefit the structure of the ideal can give but an arbitrary index set can't.)

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.